# LINQ query taking long time

Tags: performance, linq

Following query i write it returns me 1400 records. and below line taking much time.

1.5 second taken by

```
count = quer != null ? quer.Count() : 0;
```

and 2 sec taken by

```
candidateList = quer.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The LINQ tools are very handy for developers, but they were never guaranteed to perform better than ugly CAML code or be more resilient to user changes (*hint: they rely on display names that may change*), for that matter.

Look into ULS logs (`Set-SPLogLevel -Trace Verbose`) for answers in the Database category.

Moreover, I assume you're doing this from a Console executable on a development machine, right?

Try SQL Server Management Studio's profiler or other tools to understand what's the load on SQL Database, how are the indexes/indices and execution plans (mis)used. Sometimes you might find useful to check for database fragmentation.

Comment: No ,i am not using console.Is there any other code that can be replace it.

Comment: ((SPList)list).GetItems((SPQuery) query).Count for the first line. Of course, you should build a proper query first.